# Utc Date saving as Local date in Sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, datetime, dapper

I have an Sql database which contains a date field.

I use Dapper to update the database as follows:

```
const string sql = "UPDATE AdminDb.Users " +
                   "SET IsLoggedOn = 1, LastLoggedOn = @LastLoggedOn " +
                   "WHERE Username = @username";
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
DatabaseConnectionBase.DatabaseConnection.Execute(sql, new { username, LastLoggedOn = date });
```

I am finding to my great annoyance when breaking before the actual update, the date variable reads **30/3/2015 9:32:54** however when I run the update the database saves the date as **30/3/2015 10:32:54**

As the UK yesterday changed from GMT to BST (UTC +1) I am sure that the database seems to be trying to compensate for this as this issue never came up before.

I thought I had averted this sort of issue by using the DateTime.UtcNow property to save my date.

This is causing serious issues when validating users.

- I am sure it is not my code as the date is correct going into the Dapper Execute method.
- I can't see why Dapper would try to compensate as most developers would be screaming at such functionality
- Which leads me to the conclusion that it must be something in Sqlite that is causing this issue. Perhaps there is a pragma I need to run?

As per a suggestion from another site I tried formatting the date as follows:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

The intention being to force the date into ISO-8601 format but I had no luck with that.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Where is this database exactly? On your local machine? Or another server? Did you debug your code and see what `DateTime.UtcNow` returns exactly?

Comment: Yes I did debug my code, the date variable reads the correct UTC date for as long as I can see it until it goes into the Dapper Execute method. The database is on a remote server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me too. 
What I did was serialize the datetime to a string myself before adding it as a parameter.

```
internal const string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Threshold", DbType.DateTime).Value = threshold.ToString(DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 16):

Thomas Levesque has the solution [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/28/how-to-retrieve-dates-as-utc-in-sqlite/):

```
// You just need to specify DateTimeKind=Utc in your connection string:
string connectionString = @"Data Source=D:\tmp\testSQLiteDate.db;DateTimeKind=Utc";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do the same thing with pure ADO.NET, does the same thing happen? I wonder if this is a database thing or a provider thing, rather than a library thing. Dapper has to `ToLocalTime()` or `ToUniversalTime()` calls - it passes the time through unaltered. On SQL Server, the following works fine in a BST setting:

```
    public void SO29343103_UtcDates()
    {
        const string sql = "select @date";
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var returned = connection.Query<DateTime>(sql, new { date }).Single();
        var delta = returned - date;
        Assert.IsTrue(delta.TotalMilliseconds >= -1 && delta.TotalMilliseconds <= 1);
    }
```